# This World Cup vs In this World Cup

Tags: prepositions

> "I'm pretty sure Antoine Griezmann is going to score the most goals this World Cup," he said.

Vs

> "I'm pretty sure Antoine Griezmann is going to score the most goals **in** this World Cup," he said.

Is "this" preceded by "in" preposition in the above example? Or not?

Comment: Maybe "to score most of the goals"?

Comment: @Rompey: By default, that would mean something different. OP's version implies Griezmann will score more more goals than any other *individual* player, but yours implies he'll score *more than all other players in total*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are acceptable. In the first sentence "this" is necessary.  In the second sentence "this" could be replaced by "the" as it is obvious from the context that you are talking about the current (2018) World Cup.